# Как взять значение из placeholder?

Tags: javascript, php

Как сделать условие в action если value пустой(никто не написал в окошечко), то брать из placeholder

```
<form method="post"  action="next.php" >
<input type="text" id="search-box" name="sel"  placeholder='.$data.' value=""/>
<button type="submit">Otpravit</button>
```

Comment: Вам в php его надо передать? В PHP уходит value, а плейсхолдер что бы показать что примерно вводить в поле

Comment: Собственно отсюда вывод, в PHP проверяем пусто или нет, или сделать скрытое поле

Comment: Просто добавьте значение по умолчанию на стороне сервера. placeholder - просто gui, он не передаётся на сервер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let inp = document.querySelector("input");
let sbm = document.querySelector("form button");
let form = document.querySelector("form");

//alert(inp.getAttribute("placeholder"));

sbm.onclick = function(){
  if ((inp.value !== undefined || inp.value !== null) && inp.value === ""){
    inp.value = inp.getAttribute("placeholder");
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post"  action="" onsubmit="console.log($(this).serialize());return false">
<input type="text" id="search-box" name="sel"  placeholder='123' value=""/>
<button type="submit">Otpravit</button>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

Comment: значит у вас `inp` (в моем коде) не находит по слеектору

Comment: делал поиск по ID тож не выводит

Comment: @Bloom обновил код..теперь можно проверить...jquery для наглядной демонстрации (не более)

Comment: да скрипт ниже кнопки надо было )

Comment: `if (inp.value === undefined || inp.value === null || inp.value === ""){` жестоко!

Comment: @РустамГимранов опечатка) исправился ) спасибо

Answer (score 1):

C помощью js бери.
placeholder это атрибут. получить значения атрибута можно

```
var el = document.getElementById('search-box');
var placeholder = el.getAttribute("placeholder");
```